# A point out of a convex set is not a limit point

Tags: general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis

> Let $S$ be a non-empty convex set in $\mathbb R^2$ (note, $S$ is not necessarily closed) such that $S$ is bounded from below, i.e. there exists a real constant $C$ such that for any $(t_1,t_2)\in S$, $t_1>C, t_2>C$.
>
> For any point $a=(a_1,a_2)\in \mathbb R^2$ define $B_a=(-\infty,a_1]\times (-\infty,a_2]$, i.e. the set of points that lie below $a$ (including $a$) in the Cartesian plane. Suppose $x=(x_1,x_2)\in S$ is such that $B_x\cap S=\{x\}$ i.e. the only point from $S$ that lies in $B_x$ is $x$ only (equivalently, no point from $S$ lies strictly below $x$). Note these things can be defined since $S$ is assumed to be non-empty bounded from below.
>
> Let $y=(y_1,y_2)\notin S$ be a point such that $y_1=x_1$ and $y_2<x_2$. Then obviously $y\in B_x$. Then, prove that $y$ can't be a limit point of $S$.

I tried to proceed by contradiction. If $y$ is a limit point of $S$ then there is a sequence $z_n=(z_{n1},z_{n2})\in S$ such that $z_n\to y$. Since $y_2<x_2$, we can choose subsequence  $z_{n_k}$ such that $z_{n_k,2}<x_2$. Let us call this subsequence $z_n$ again, for simplicity, as we can work with just this sequence. Note, if for some $n$, $z_{n1}\leq x_1$, then as $z_{n2}<x_2$, we have $z_n\in S\cap B_x$ with $z_n\neq x$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, for all $n$, $z_{n1}>x_1$. I want to get a contradiction.

I tried to draw some figures to see what is happening. It seems the convexity of $S$ is the main property that is preventing the convergence of $z_n$ to $y$ if the above conditions are met. However I am not able to use this convexity property. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem as stated is false. Consider $S = ((0, 1)\times (0, 1))\cup \{(0, 1)\}$, i.e. the union of the open square with its top-left corner. $S$ is convex and bounded below. Then, let $x = (0, 1)$ and $y = (0, 0)$. Notice that $B_x\cap S = \{x\}$ and that $y\in B_x$. However, $y$ is indeed a limit point of $S$.

Comment: Very nice. But, what if you add the point $(0,0)$ to $S$? Then can it be proven that if $y_1=0$ and $y_2<0$ then $y$ is not a limit point?

Comment: Sure, although that would be a different set, and adding $(0, 0)$ makes that particular problem trivial. You'd have to impose some extra restrictions to disallow examples like the one I gave.

Comment: Yes, but I am interested to see if one can to generalize this to any other convex set. Anyway, as it is, the theorem is false, so maybe I will ask a new question including the conditions that are actually present in the theorem ;) I did not want to give away the whole theorem.